# Generating a dict from a list of tuples using dict() builtin

Tags: python, dictionary

I was surprised that both examples in the code block below return the same value. How does the dict() builtin accept the second syntax (the one that is not a generator expression)? Is this handled by the parser?

```
>>> words = ['cat','dog','frog']
>>> dict([(word, True) for word in words])
{'dog': True, 'frog': True, 'cat': True}
>>> dict((word, True) for word in words)
{'dog': True, 'frog': True, 'cat': True}
```

Comment: The second syntax _is_ a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).  The first is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both examples are **iterables**, so you could write it "long-hand" the same way:

[Generator](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators):

```
generator_construct = ((word, True) for word in words)
d = {}
for key, value in generator_construct:
    d[key] = value
```

[List comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list_construct = [(word, True) for word in words]
d = {}
for key, value in list_construct:
    d[key] = value
```

Both can be iterated the same way. The only difference is the list comprehension builds a real list, and the generator yields values one at a time. For a large number of items, the list comprehension will have more overhead because of the extra storage.

A third option given as comment by @JonClements:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(words, True)
```

Of the two, this is closest to the generator in that it doesn't build a key/value list, but it works directly over the `words` iterable.

Comment: In the OP's question, for non mutable values, it might be worth adding the best way would be: `dict.fromkeys(words, True)`

Answer (score 2):

The second syntax is, in fact, a generator expression.

See [PEP-289](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). It even includes the following example:

```
d = dict( (k, func(k)) for k in keylist)
```

which is almost exactly what you've got.

The first syntax is a [list comprehension](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm), a somewhat similar but distinct construct.

One key difference as applied to your example is that the first version creates and discards a temporary list, whereas the second doesn't.